# Incomparable types: String and class name

Tags: java

I want to make a program that can search for books in a library. But i found the error on if part for search a book in that list:

```
incomparable types: String and perpus
```

there are the main and classes code:

```
package stackoverflow.types;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Perpustakaan {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Teknologi
        arrayBuku buku1 = new arrayBuku();
        buku1.Perpus[0] = new perpus("Penggunaan Bahasa C++ Untuk Robotik", "Dijeh Zedd", "Teknologi");
        buku1.Perpus[1] = new perpus("Pemrograman iPhone Untuk Pemula", "Martin Gerixx", "Teknologi");
        buku1.Perpus[2] = new perpus("Pemrograman Assembly Untuk Microprocessor", "Cakar Kuning", "Teknologi");

        buku1.Perpus[3] = new perpus("Sistem Digital Untuk Hobby", "Skrilek Gondrong", "Teknologi");

        buku1.Perpus[4] = new perpus("CSS dan PHP Untuk Website Cantik", "Dipha Kapur Barus", "Teknologi");

        // Filsafat
        buku1.Perpus[5] = new perpus("Filsafat Yunani dan Relevansinya Masa Kini", "Kripton Thor", "Filsafat");

        buku1.Perpus[6] = new perpus("Pengantar Filsafat I", "Logan Laura", "Filsafat");

        buku1.Perpus[7] = new perpus("Filsafat Plato dan Aristoteles", "Petrus Parkerus", "Filsafat");

        buku1.Perpus[8] = new perpus("Filsafat Untuk Mahasiswa Sosiologi", "Clark Kent", "Filsafat");

        buku1.Perpus[9] = new perpus("Relevansi Filsafat dengan Agama", "Loki Mydog", "Filsafat");

        // Sejarah
        buku1.Perpus[10] = new perpus("Nazi vs Marxisme, Sepanjang Sejarah", "Thomas Muller", "Sejarah");

        buku1.Perpus[11] = new perpus("Kebenaran Adanya Hitler di Indonesia", "Mesut Ozil", "Sejarah");

        buku1.Perpus[12] = new perpus("Jejak Raja Alexander", "Goy Agoy", "Sejarah");

        buku1.Perpus[13] = new perpus("Sejarah Thailand", "Panyanut Machaporn", "Sejarah");

        buku1.Perpus[14] = new perpus("Majapahit: Berdiri, Runtuh", "Salsabila Multazam", "Sejarah");

        // Agama
        buku1.Perpus[15] = new perpus("Cara Mencapai Nirwana Tanpa Moksa", "Mahagyana", "Agama");

        buku1.Perpus[16] = new perpus("Tafsir Perjanjian Baru Alkitab Untuk Masa Kini", "Petrus Marwanto", "Agama");

        buku1.Perpus[17] = new perpus("Pengetahuan Islam Untuk Masyarakat Awam", "Syafril Mawardah", "Agama");

        buku1.Perpus[18] = new perpus("Nilai-Nilai Dewa Wisnu Untuk Manusia", "I Gede Sukarna", "Agama");

        buku1.Perpus[19] = new perpus("Ajaran Konfusius", "John Xie", "Agama");

        // Psikologi
        buku1.Perpus[20] = new perpus("Psikologi Bagi Militer", "Letnan Ilham Irwinansyah M.Psi", "Psikologi");

        buku1.Perpus[21] = new perpus("Orang Aneh dari Sudut Pandang Psikologi", "Ichsan Eftepe", "Psikologi");

        buku1.Perpus[22] = new perpus("Psikologi balita", "Dr. Prof. Ir. Fajrul M.Psi", "Psikologi");

        buku1.Perpus[23] = new perpus("Penanganan Sikap Psikologi Lansia", "Imad Muzhaffar, S.Psi", "Psikologi");

        buku1.Perpus[24] = new perpus("Biologi Psikologi Jilid III", "Abas Saritua Gultom", "Psikologi");

        // Politik
        buku1.Perpus[25] = new perpus("Pengantar Ilmu Politik I", "Maikel Fernanda Pasaribu", "Politik");

        buku1.Perpus[26] = new perpus("Menangani Kelicikan Politik di Indonesia", "Aldy Bahagia", "Politik");

        buku1.Perpus[27] = new perpus("Politik: Kolonial, Jepang, Kemerdekaan, Hingga Reformasi", "Aldy Belajar",
                "Politik");

        buku1.Perpus[28] = new perpus("Politik di Partai Masa Kini", "Dr. Raihan Suwanto, M.Pol", "Politik");

        buku1.Perpus[29] = new perpus("Sistem Politik Liberal", "dr. Dr. Ir. Samuel Bayu Sentosa", "Politik");

        // Fiksi
        buku1.Perpus[30] = new perpus("Dilan Versi Baru Yey", "Naufal Eginda", "Fiksi");

        buku1.Perpus[31] = new perpus("Senja Dilambai Bayu", "Febryanto Marthin Simanjuntak", "Fiksi");

        buku1.Perpus[32] = new perpus("Terbuai Angin", "Matsari Buerte", "Fiksi");

        buku1.Perpus[33] = new perpus("Distraksi Kalbu", "Manuel Nicholas", "Fiksi");

        buku1.Perpus[34] = new perpus("Melayangkan Asa di Kala Gelap", "Ihramsyah Faishal", "Fiksi");

        String cari;
        System.out.println("Masukkan buku yang ingin dicari: ");
        cari = in.nextLine();
        if (cari == buku1.Perpus[1]) {

        }

    }

}

class perpus {
    private String penulis;
    private String namaBuku;
    private String kategori; // teknologi, filsafat, sejarah,agama, psikologi,
                                // politik dan fiksi.

    public perpus() {
        namaBuku = "";
        penulis = "";
        kategori = "";
    }

    public perpus(String a, String b, String c) {
        namaBuku = a;
        penulis = b;
        kategori = c;
    }

    public void setPenulis(String s) {
        penulis = s;
    }

    public void setNamaBuku(String s) {
        namaBuku = s;
    }

    public void setKategori(String s) {
        kategori = s;
    }

    public void cariBuku(String s) {
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(namaBuku) || s.equalsIgnoreCase(kategori) || s.equalsIgnoreCase(penulis)) {
            System.out.println("Buku tersedia");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Buku tidak tersedia");
        }

    }

    public void setBuku(String a, String b, String c) {
        namaBuku = a;
        penulis = b;
        kategori = c;
    }

    public void cetak() {
        System.out.println("Buku Anda berjudul: " + namaBuku);
        System.out.println("Penulis buku Anda adalah: " + penulis);
        System.out.println("Kategori buku Anda adalah: " + kategori);
        System.out.println("=========================================");

    }
}

class arrayBuku {
    private String penulis;
    private String namaBuku;
    private String kategori;
    public int jumlah = 35;
    perpus[] Perpus = new perpus[jumlah];
}
```

sorry, i used Indonesian language for variable names and book attributes (such as author, title and category). Does anyone know how to fix the error? Thanks.

Comment: The first step would be read the exact and complete error message, which contains the location of the error.

Comment: You can do SomeClass.getName() or grtSimpleName(). And then read about java coding guides. Class names start upper case, variable names start lower case. You are doing things exactly the opposite wrong way there.

Comment: no, i just want to make 'if statement' for searching a book in the list, but there is the error that string cannot be compared with a class. How to fix that?

Comment: Waaaay too much code here. Learn to write a [MCVE] you will often solve the issue yourself doing so.

Comment: Unrelated, but you're totally violating [Java naming conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2697/oracle-official-code-standard/9031/naming-conventions#t=201703171903113357752). Class names should start with uppercase letter, and field names should start with lowercase letter. You're doing the exact opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the error is thrown at this line

```
 if(cari == buku1.Perpus[1])
```

Since you're comparing a String to a Perpus object in your array here.

You need to add some getter methods to your class, so that you can compare Strings in your array elements to the String cari.

Eg:

```
class perpus {
    private String penulis;
    private String namaBuku;
    private String kategori; 

    String getPenulis()
    {
    return penulis;
    }
    //insert other class members here

    }
```

Then:

```
if(cari.equals(buku1.Perpus[1].getPenulis()))
//do whatever
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String cari;
System.out.println("Masukkan buku yang ingin dicari: ");
cari = in.nextLine();
if(cari == buku1.Perpus[1])
```

Since *cari* is a string, one problem you may encounter is in java using "==" on a string compares the string object to another object.
It is advised to use *cari*.equals(*other string*).

Also, you are comparing a string to a *Perpus* object. Ultimately you should use

```
if(cari.equals(buku1.Perpus[1].get###()))
```

with ### being whatever property of *Perpus* cari relates to